# Transferring name of column to a function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function which returns specific details about outliers (only sex, age, education, and the outlying value). I need to do it with many parameters, so I would like to transfer name of column to the function. Is there a way to do it?

For example, this code should return: f, 27, 12, 110.

```
my_data= data.frame( sex= c("f", "m", "f", "f", "m"),
                     age= c(22, 30, 24, 27, 30),
                     eduyears= c(12,16, 15, 12, 17),
                     weight= c(53, 70, 60, 110, 75),
                     height= c(160, 183, 157, 168, 180))

find_outliers= function (my_data, colname) {
  out_values= boxplot.stats(my_data$colname)$out
  out_ind= which(my_data$colname %in% out_values) #find outliers indices
  outliers= my_data[out_ind ,c("sex","age","eduyears", colname)] 
  return (outliers)
}

find_outliers(weight)
```

Comment: Put the column name in quotes, i.e. do `find_outlyers("weight")` and instead of `my_data$colname` do `my_data[[colname]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function has two arguments you need to pass them both in its call, you are only passing one, `weight`. And passing as an unquoted variable means the function must get the column name as a character string in order to access it.

Finally, see the famous question on how to [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names).

```r
my_data <- data.frame(sex = c("f", "m", "f", "f", "m"),
                      age = c(22, 30, 24, 27, 30),
                      eduyears = c(12,16, 15, 12, 17),
                      weight = c(53, 70, 60, 110, 75),
                      height = c(160, 183, 157, 168, 180))

find_outliers <- function (my_data, colname) {
  # get the colname as a character string
  colname <- as.character(substitute(colname))
  out_values <- boxplot.stats(my_data[[colname]])$out
  out_ind <- which(my_data[[colname]] %in% out_values) #find outliers indices
  outliers <- my_data[out_ind, c("sex","age","eduyears", colname)] 
  outliers
}

find_outliers(my_data, weight)
#>   sex age eduyears weight
#> 4   f  27       12    110

my_data |> find_outliers(weight)
#>   sex age eduyears weight
#> 4   f  27       12    110
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helped me a lot to figure out few basic concepts.